# How often is fsync called in everyday usage?

Tags: filesystems

Say I spend some time as a user interacting with a filesystem, using commands such as `cp`, `mv`, `mkdir` and `rm`. None of these commands call `fsync` in normal operation.

Can a filesystem run indefinitely without fsyncing? Does that put my data at risk? Should I be trying to determine how long it's been since the last fsync?

Comment: When life was simpler, Linux had a kernel task `pdflush` which ran every 30 seconds to put written pages on the i/o queue for the device according to some algorithm. This was replaced in 2009, see this [lwn article](https://lwn.net/Articles/326552/).

Answer (score 7):

The short answer is: yes, yes, no.

Yes, a file system can run indefinitely without applications calling `fsync`: file systems don’t rely on that to ensure data (eventually) gets stored on disk, there are other mechanisms in place. Not having `fsync` calls does put your data slightly at risk: for example, if you copy a file and delete the original, then your system loses power, there’s a slight chance that the deletion will make it to the disk but the copy will be incomplete.

There are usually configuration settings you can change to control how fast the operating system tries to store data on disk; there’s also the big stick, `sync`, which causes all outstanding data to be written. (Note that in all cases, the operating system can only ensure the data makes it to the disk controller, and perhaps ask the disks to flush their buffers — there is no absolute guarantee that the data is actually stored on disk.)

On Linux, the settings you can tweak are in `/proc/sys/vm`; the corresponding documentation is [`admin-guide/sysctl/vm.rst`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/vm.html#dirty-background-bytes) — look for `dirty_`. The various settings allow you to specify how much data can be waiting to be written, or for how long, before the operating system starts writing it to disk. There are two mechanisms which can step in here: there’s a background thread which writes pending data to disk (`dirty_background_...`), and when processes start producing too much data, the operating system will cause their writes to flush to disk (effectively introducing something like `fsync`). The reason there are two mechanisms is that the operating system tries to preserve a balance between I/O performance and processing performance: as long as the running processes aren’t writing data too fast, the background thread takes care of it; but once they start writing too much data for the disks to keep up, they are slowed down, which both helps the system catch up with writing pending data, and avoids too much more data being written.

If you’re worried about your data, don’t try to check out whether `fsync` has been called, just run `sync`.

(Ignore `/proc/sys/vm/dirtytime_expire_seconds`, that’s something else entirely.)